# Getting started with Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio and it's tutorials and examples

Tags: robotics-studio

I am a newbie in using Microsoft Robotics Developer studio and I want to make an advanced line follower using Microsoft Robotics Developer studio and it's simulator. Can anyone tell me how can I do this setup and a sample program to check my simulator? Right now I have downloaded and installed robotics developer studio on my laptop but I am not getting how shall I use it to see the simulation. And I also need some examples and tutorials on it. I searched on it but I am not getting good materials on it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a line follower sample refenced here

http://www.microsoft.com/robotics/#Learn

also check out http://www.helloapps.net

Answer (score 3):

I can help you with a list with [simulation tutorials for Robotics Developer Studio](http://www.intorobotics.com/robotics-developer-studio-simulation-tutorials/)